# Creating Middleware in Blazor WASM To Capture Page Events

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM Core Hosted Application (three projects: Client, Server, Shared) using .Net 7.  I am trying to create an audit trail feature in my Blazor WASM Core Hosted Single Page App. Ideally, I would like a solution that I can implement in one place and would not require every page to have to implement a complicated solution.  I am trying to avoid doing this on the front end as well (I don't want to introduce any more latency to the system if there is poor connections).  I would prefer middleware, if that is possible?

I have written two functionalities to try and solve this but they both have challenges I cannot overcome.  First, I wrote an attribute class I can add to all of my API endpoints, which allows me to pass in a message (like the page URL).  But, the problem with this is that API's may get called by multiple pages or multiple times in a page or there may be no API for a page.  Here is the code for that:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class PageActionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string NameValue { get; }
    public PageActionAttribute(string nameValue)
    {
        NameValue = nameValue;       
    }
}
```

Then I can add this to my API methods, in my controller: `[PageAction("/api/admin/create-user-account")]`.  Additionally, if I had a method like `[HttpGet("get-user-id/{emailAddress}")]` using that in my attribute like this: `[PageAction("get-user-id/{emailAddress}")]` would not show the actual parameter.  I suppose I could create an endpoint to just register when the user hits the page, and maybe have it in a base class that all pages inherit from.  But, I am not sure how to get the full URL from the methods attribute?

I then have middleware that can get that attribute:

```
public class UserAccessMiddleware
  {   
      public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
      {
          //option 1
      string attributeValue = GetCustomAttributeValue(context);
        //option 2
         string referer = context.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();            
          await _next(context);    }  
      private string GetCustomAttributeValue(HttpContext context)
      {    
        if (context.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<PageActionAttribute>() is PageActionAttribute attribute)
        {
            return attribute.NameValue;
        }        
      }
```

The scenario 2 I looked at was using the same middleware but capturing this:  `string referrer = context.Request.Headers["Referer"];` but the problem with that is the Invoke method gets called multiple times for a page, and therefore would get logged multiple times per page.  I dont see a way to determine if the context.Request.Headers["Referer"] was the first (or last) request for the page.  If I could only limit that code from being called once per page, that would allow me to then generate a log for every page view event.

Is there any way to address the two options I started or another way to create middleware to do this?